# Not sure what affecting button display - updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have and radio button selection and given each radio button a progress bar, progress bar are `display:none` but when selected a radio progress bar will `show()`, same to the button.

Now my problem is sometime when I selected a radio button, the button show like this:

[image]

But sometime when I selected a radio button, the button has been push to the bottom and cant even seen:

[image]

I not sure where this problem come from, but I guest maybe the progress bar blocked it? 
Maybe I have miss something in my code that I don't know. Anyone able to help me check for this problem ?

[Click here for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v07vt9gz/)

**Updated part**

I found out how to make the button push to bottom , hover in and hover out the div 4 to 5 times then select one option, then the button will push to bottom. So far haven't found any solution, anyone know how to fixed please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: problem exists just in Chrome? (I test in FireFox and Chrome - FireFox is Ok)

Comment: please give your full code

Comment: @demo i tested, FF and Chrome also have this problem, sometime show sometime push to bottom

Comment: @SameerShaikh the jsfiddle is my full code

Comment: In order to reproduce the problem you have to: Hover it, leave it before it **reaches top**, hover it again **before it reaches the bottom**, click a fruit.

Comment: @Spokey sorry I not understand

Comment: @Spokey i maybe understand what you try to say now, but do you have solution to fixed this ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-top: -22px` from `.popup_survey_whitebox_percent` and replace with

```
position: relative;
top: -22px;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v07vt9gz/2/)

Comment: can you please tell me why ? im very curious

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way to fixed this problem .

```
      $("#popup_survey_whitebox").hover(function () {
    $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').finish().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500, function () {
        $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(orig); // Here put the original text.

    }).css('position', 'relative');

}, function () {
    $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').finish().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500, function () {
        $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(newText); // Here put the new text with "..."

    }).css('position', 'relative');
});
```

**change `$('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop()` to `$('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').finish()` for both animate**

Comment: its quite comical, because the entire animations could be completed  with simple css rules, and instead allowing the javascript to focus on the content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your answer, `finish` works, but introduces some quirkiness for the experience if you hover in/out quickly (it jumps to the end of the animtation immediately, and can "flicker").

This issue can be addressed by reseting the `height` attribute on the hover 'out' logic. When you hover in/out quickly, the height value is set, which is then used after.

Here's a fiddle with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/v07vt9gz/5/

And the logic:

```
$(this).css('height', ''); // reset value
```